# Hangouts Face icons dim to bright

Tags: google-hangouts

Help me understand icons under messages going from live then back to dim under message.
When I send a message on hangouts the contact face shows live under the message, then reverts back to dim above the message.

Answer (score 0):

So, you know how when you receive a message, there's a notification at the top of your screen? (When the icon is bright, it means person in question is looking at your message) Maybe it means that they have seen the notification, but have not yet responded and continued doing  what they had  been doing.